# Create a kivy application to take input from user in one screen and display those many images in other screen

Tags: python, file-upload, pycharm, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to create an application that would display images from a certain path in my PC.
I would like to display those images based on the user input. Let's suppose user gave a number 5, then it would display 5 images randomly in that path.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example app that should do what you asked using pure python (no KV language). Just saying, when displaying the images you may want to consider adding a scrollview to be able to view full image. Currently, I have "shrunk" them by specifing `size_hint(.3,.3)` . Also, you want to find a better way to filter out files that are not images, I created a basic filter by checking if the file path ends with ".jpg" or ".png", you could probably do this regex or use the glob library.

```
import os, random

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, NumericProperty

class Screen2(Screen):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.layout = StackLayout()
        self.random_image_number = App.get_running_app().images_num
        self.images_paths = App.get_running_app().images_paths
        self.random_paths = random.choices(self.images_paths, k=self.random_image_number)

        for path in self.random_paths:
            # You may wanna change the size_hint or add a scrollview if you want full size images
            img = Image(source=path,size_hint=(.3,.3))
            self.layout.add_widget(img)

        self.add_widget(self.layout)

class Screen1(Screen):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Add your path here
        self.image_path = os.path.join("C:\\Users\\dimit\\Pictures")
        self.layout = RelativeLayout()
        self.input_bar = TextInput(multiline=False, size_hint=(0.4, 0.1), pos_hint={"center_x":.5, "center_y":.5}, hint_text="How many images to show", input_type="number")
        self.input_bar.bind(on_text_validate=self.get_images)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.input_bar)
        self.add_widget(self.layout)

    # inst refers to the input bar object
    def get_images(self, inst):
        App.get_running_app().images_num = int(inst.text)
        for fname in os.scandir(self.image_path):
            # Skip any directories
            if fname.is_dir():
                continue
            
            # Filter for images 
            if fname.path.endswith(".jpg") or fname.path.endswith(".png"):
                App.get_running_app().images_paths.append(fname.path)

        # This line needs to be here, because if you add the screen in the build method, it wont add the images
        App.get_running_app().screen_manager.add_widget(Screen2(name="Image Display Page"))

        # Changes screen to image display screen 
        App.get_running_app().screen_manager.current = "Image Display Page"

class ImageApp(App):
    images_paths = ListProperty([])
    images_num = NumericProperty(0)
    def build(self):
        self.title = "Image Display App"
        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(Screen1(name="Home Page"))
    
        return self.screen_manager


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ImageApp().run()
```

Comment: This is the error  I am getting : Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/harsh/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/WiseTime.py", line 5, in <module>
     from kivymd.uix.MDRelativeLayout import MDRelativeLayout
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivymd.uix.MDRelativeLayout'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Do you have kivymd installed?

Comment: @SriHarsha When I was reading your question, I thought you wanted to use [KivyMD](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I edited my answer, so it will only use Kivy and not KivyMD imports.